# What is the difference between address-of and pointer address?

Tags: c++

What is difference between the plain pointer address and the "address of" the pointer ?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int * a= new int[1];
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<&a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This print two different values:

```
0x8b1a438
0xffbb6b8c
```

Comment: Try out: `cout<<*(&a)<<endl;` additionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A picture is usually worth a thousand words:

```
           +------------+
0x08b1a438 |         42 | int[1]
           +------------+
                  ^
                  |
                  |
           +------|-----+
0xffbb6b8c | 0x08b1a438 | int * a
           +------------+
```

As you can see, printing `a` prints the contents of `a`, and printing `&a` prints its address.

Answer (score 1):

This prints out the value of `a`, that is, the address it points to:

```
cout << a <<endl;
```

This prints out the address of `a` itself:

```
cout<< &a <<endl;
```

This is analogous to what happens with other built-in types, for example,

```
int b = 42;
cout << b << endl;  // prints the value of b, i.e. 42
cout << &b << endl; // prints the address of b
```

The value of a pointer just happens to be an address of another object. The values of both `a` and `b` can change. Their address can't.

```
a = &b; // modify value of a: now it points to b.
b = 99; // modify the value of b: now it is 99.
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a pointer variable, and contains the adress of the integer.

`&a` is the adress of the pointer variable itself, i.e. it is the adress which holds the adress of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10, ptr;
    ptr = &a;  //its check the address using(&)operator
    printf("the value of *p%d\n", *ptr); 
    printf("the value of a:%d\n", a);
    printf("the address of ptr=>%p\n", ptr);
    printf("the address of &ptr=>%p\n", &ptr);
    printf("the address of a=>%p\n", &a); 
}
output:
   ./a.out 
   the value of *p10
   the value of a:10
   the address of ptr=>0x7fff62db082c
   the address of &ptr=>0x7fff62db0830
   the address of a=>0x7fff62db082c

**i anwswerd in c its easy to understand**
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value